# Rearranging infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Is the computation
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k = a_2+a_1+a_4+a_3...$$
valid?

I think that it is a valid rearrangment because the permutation function is bijective, and the computation is valid if the original series is unconditionally convergent. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Before you mess around with an infinite sum, you better be dang sure it converges.

Comment: If the $a_k$ values are all nonnegative, then teh summation is independent of order.

Comment: Yes, because the unconditional convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence.

Comment: More generally, the summation is independent of order if and only if either $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \max[a_k,0]<\infty$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \max[-a_k,0]<\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ be convergent series (it doesn't have to be absolute convergent). Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and $t_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k$ where $b_k=a_{k+1}$ for k odd and $b_k=a_{k-1}$ for k even. Then $|s_n-t_n|\leq|a_n|+|a_{n+1}|\rightarrow 0$, so $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$