# Convergence of rearranged infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is nonabsolutely convergent. Then does 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k = a_2+a_1+a_4+a_3...?
$$

I'm not sure how to determine whether this rearrangement changes the value of the sum. Would it depend on the fact that the original series does not converge absolutety? How would I prove this?

Comment: The Riemann series theorem states that if a series is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent, you may rearrange its terms through a permutation in order that the new series is conditionally convergent to $\alpha$, for **any** $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ of your choice. So, in general, $$\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n = \sum_{n\geq 1}a_{\sigma(n)}$$ **does not** hold.

Answer (score 0):

[Rearranging infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970427/rearranging-infinite-series/1970449#1970449)

You asked the same question yesterday, and I already answered it!

Comment: But why doesn't the fact that the series is nonabsolutely convergent play into the answer? I thought that you can only rearrange an absolutely convergent series?

Comment: @Mathematically some rearrangements are much more destructive than others.  For example rearranging $1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ into the order $1,5,2,25,3,125,4,625,6,3125,7,\dots$.  Rearranging just by swapping pairs is not nearly as destructive.

Comment: It depends on how you rearrange the terms. If the series is absolute convergent you can rearrange them any way you like.

Comment: So in general is there any "easy" way to tell if the rearrangement changes the sum of the series?

Comment: Well if you only rearrange finite terms the series won't change. If you only interchange the first $n_1$ terms with each other, then the next $n_2$ terms with each other etc. the series won't change its value. Not sure what you can say more in general.

Answer (score 0):

The even partial sums are unchanged and the odd partial sums of the rearranged series approach the odd partial sums of the original series since the terms approach zero. Therefore I would say that the limit is unchanged.